# Ubuntu WSL Community Preview Has Duplicate Entries in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two Ubuntu WSL installations. One is the the most recent LTS release from the Windows Store, the other is the WSL Community Preview Release ([details here)](https://ubuntu.com/blog/announcing-ubuntu-on-windows-community-preview-wsl-2).

However, three Ubuntu entries show up in Windows Terminal.

[image]

I have accessed the latter two and found they point to the same thing, but one is without the Ubuntu purple background and has the name variation in the menu.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature. :0)

Comment: What does `wsl -l -v` show?  You may have one registered that got "reset" in the Community Preview that may need to be removed with `wsl --unregister <distroname>`.  Be *very careful*, of course with this if you need to use it -- It will remove all data associated with the instance.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds How do you do that formatting in your comment?

Comment: It's [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) formatting, an amazing tool for inline formatting, supported by many websites including those here on Stack Exchange, Reddit, Github, and many others.  Oddly, the inline code formatting isn't provided on that help page, but it uses backticks.  E.g. \`this here\` results in `this here`.  Sad side-note regarding one of the [Markdown creators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds That formatting isn't working for me, so I'll answer your original question with [a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/9qn1IUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on.

There are currently (at least) three ways that Windows Terminal profiles can be created:

- Through [Dynamic Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles), where Windows Terminal will automatically generate a profile for each instance of certain environments (Windows PowerShell and WSL).
- Manually through the Settings UI (which in turn modifies the `settings.json`)
- The newest method, [json fragment extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/json-fragment-extensions), which allows third-party applications to create or update profiles.

The two profiles in your list with the Penguin icon are the ones dynamically generated.  For each entry in `wsl -l`, Windows Terminal generates a profile.

The "Ubuntu on Windows Community Preview" is almost certainly being generated by a json fragment from its installation.  Canonical's announcement page that you linked to specifically says that's one of the new features:

> 3. Windows Terminal Fragment Extension: A work-in-progress extension that provides an entry on Windows Terminal

They do say it's a "work-in-progress", but I do think that the fact that it generates a *separate* profile is a bug.  I seem to recall (although I can't find the reference page) that dynamic profile GUID's should always match based on the generator and the profile name.  So "Ubuntu-CommPrev" *should* always have the same profile ID, and that is the GUID that the json fragment should be able to update.  That would leave only one Preview profile in your Windows Terminal, the one that Canonical has customized.

Anyway, as long as this isn't happening, you should still be able to "hide" the one you don't want (probably the dynamic profile).  Just use the Settings UI in the "Ubuntu-CommPrev" profile to set the "Hide profile from dropdown" to "On".

Alternatively, edit the `settings.json` to add:

```
"hidden": "true"
```

to that profile.